# Why is "result = list_data.remove(element_value)" wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. This code is right:

   ```
   def delete_a_list_element(list_data, element_value):
       result =[]
       if not (element_value in list_data) :
           return 0
       else :
           while (element_value in list_data) :
               list_data.remove(element_value)
               result = list_data
           return result
   ```
2. This code is wrong:

   ```
   def delete_a_list_element(list_data, element_value):
       result =[]
       if not (element_value in list_data) :
           return 0
       else :
           while (element_value in list_data) :
               result = list_data.remove(element_value)

           return result
   ```

I don't know why (2) is wrong.

Comment: That function doesn't really make sense. Why does it return zero or the list? Also the assignment to result seems pointless in either case, as what you are implementing is just `return list_data`. But Python methods and functions that mutate their subject (like remove!) conventionally don't return anything. It's not clear why you'd expect to return the list, it's not what the docs say it does.

Comment: I got your point, but it was just one part of the processes required in my assignment. It's pointless to find any meaning in it:) Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return `list_data.remove(element_value)`, but you cant do that since "remove" is an in-built function in Python which returns None. The first example works because you are returning the list_data after you've done the removal

Comment: You could add that the `list.remove(x)` does not return anything, it's a `void` method. It updates the list but does not return anything.

Comment: Wow now I realized a new fact! Thank you so much! Many blessings to you:)

Answer (score 0):

The second approach returns `None` because of the `list.remove()` method . By Default The `remove()` doesn't return any value (`returns None`).That's why the `result is None` instead of the `new list` in the second approach